# How to stop android poweroff request in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I was trying to dismiss the power off request so that I can avoid power off request in android but i am not able to achieve this.

Could someone please help me out on this?

Manifest File

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
<receiver android:name=".PowerRequest">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In Reciever

```
if (paramIntent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"))
{
  //handling to dismiss the System Dialogs. But this is not happening.. Did some thing like 
Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);


    sendBroadcast(closeDialog);

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that in a non-rooted device.

Comment: I'm not even sure that root would be sufficient. `DEVICE_POWER` is a `signature`-level permission, for example. The power-off dialog should not be a "temporary system dialog" and hence affected by `ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS`. And, by the time `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` is broadcast, the user has already indicated they want to power down the device. A custom ROM mod could handle it, though I cannot imagine what users would want to install a ROM mod whose purpose is to prevent them from powering off the device.